# Replace/Remove only the first occurrence found in a string

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I have a string like this: `file-name-example-data`.
I want to remove only the first dash (`-`) found in the string.
Basically I want this output: `filename-example-data`.
What bash command do you propose to use? Could any sed or awk command work?

The string can be have any length and any amount of dash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `sub` function of GNU AWK following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
file-name-example-data
```

then

```
awk '{sub("-","");print}' file.txt
```

output

```
filename-example-data
```

Explanation: `sub` function replaces leftmost occurence of `-` with empty string, i.e. remove it, as I used 2 argument form it work on whole line. `print` alone does print whole line as changed. If you want to know more about `sub` read [String Functions manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html).

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Comment: I don't have a file. It is just a variable. Can the command you suggest still work?

Comment: I am unable to say without having wider scope, but if you do not want use file you might feed awk using standard output redirection, in this case it would be `echo "file-name-example-data" | awk '{sub("-","");print}'`

Comment: Are you sure this `echo "file-name-example-data" > awk '{sub("-","");print}' ` works?

Comment: ok, you changed the answer. With the pipe, works

Comment: Note, that this solution will only substitute first occurrence of one dash.

Answer (score 1):

Use sed like this

```sh
sed 's/-\+//' input
```

**Explanation:** Substitute (`s`) first instance of one or more occurrences of `-`.

I would use awk in this way:

```
awk '{sub(/-+/,"")}1' input
```

Answer (score 1):

With the string

```
a="file-name-example-data"
```

You can use

```
echo "${a/-}"
filename-example-data
```